# My excel file keeps freezing

Tags: excel, freeze

I have a file with the usual sumifs and vlookups. Nothing complicated computationally!

It has a lot of conditional formatting

As I remove the formulas the wait cursor remains there for shorter and shorter.
When I remove all the formulas and the formatting the file is fine as in I do not get the wait cursor. What is left is a file with no calculations and flat data.

Even with calculations that are just summing I am getting the wait cursor

I have tried excel open and repair. This does not work.

My sumifs have been changed to refer to a finite array as opposed to whole columns (which are also finite for the pedantic! but say these are infinite)

I think what I want to know, is what is known to cause a wait cursor to appear in excel? What can I do to minimize the time that the wait cursor appears?

I have looked on google and am not finding anything useful or relevant to my problem

I am starting to realise that wait cursor seems to always appear for a split second when I insert a column! however with my few sumifs formulas the wait cursor is getting longer and longer. Is it possible for sumifs formulas to calculate quickly but add to the wait cursor time the more sumifs you add?

Old question :

I have an excel file that keeps freezing

It calculates and saves very quickly. it is only 3090kb

Every time I insert a column or add a sheet for example I get the egg timer and if I click it starts to say 'not responding'

It only happens with this file so I don't believe it is my computer or excel version

the file was working fine before. I extended the formulas in about ten tabs (although not that many calcs added) and then it started to freeze

even if I delete every tab so there is just a blank sheet in the file it still freezes

Please help. Thanks

Please do not answer yet,  I am still investigating and will get back to this. thank you

EDIT: The WAIT cursor not egg timer

Comment: Egg timer? What version of Windows & Office are you using?  Also, `It only happens with this file` is absolutely no proof that it's not because of your computer or excel version.  It probably **is** unrelated, but the fact that there's a reason the possibility even crossed your mind is enough of a reason to confirm that it isn't related to those items.

Comment: Also, a lot more information would be helpful such as *examples* of what kind of data you have have, what you tried, what your specific problem is (does it ever end?  How?), and what you need in the end. Please check out the [tour], ask well as [ask] and also [mcve].  If you added more formulas and now it does this, it sure doesn't *sound* like it `calculates and saves very quickly`.  Kind of the opposite.  Also, size doesn't matter.

Comment: It DOES calculate and save very quickly. I'm not for certain I am it excludes the issue of my version of excel

Comment: Also! I just call it an egg timer as I don't know what the modern version of this is called but I know people would relate and understand! I appreciate it is not enough info, but I thought the fact that it does this even with no data in the tabs would be enough to suggest it's not the content. however I have since tried something else (outlined below) and it does not happen with no data (i/e/ a new blank sheet) so i believe it is something in the formulas.

Comment: I understand having a clear question is important (I work as an analyst and this happens a lot to me). I just genuinely thought there's an issue with the file and it's something underlying

Comment: I think it's very rude to assume I am using an old windows version and then berate me for assuming that it is not my excel. It is hypocritical! athoguh I apologise, it is hasty of me

Comment: I was not entirely sure the size would matter, I had an feeling it might not! but I thought it could be a factor or someone would think it is. I am not an expert with computers, however I am surrounded by very competetant people in my team who cannot figure it out so I am turning to a forum as a last resort

Comment: , it sure doesn't sound like it calculates and saves very quickly. Kind of the opposite. Also, size doesn't matter. - This comment is very frustrating! This is the exact reason I turning to stack overflow - It is an unusual case! This is what I have said, I am not lying or making this up. what a waste of time that would be!

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any hidden sheets with the data that is slowing it down. 
Right click on sheet tab and unhide.

Make this practice to use this Macro or set Row Height to 15 so they don't Wrap. Wraptext in large excel files causes it to slow down to the point of freezing:

`activesheet.cells.wraptext = false`

Comment: Ok thank you. there is nothing hidden, I have also run the macro, it is still slow.

Comment: I realise the book is fine if I delete all sheets! Previously I deleted everything and it was still slow. I cut all the tables into another sheet and this one is fine when I delete everything. I will try deleting sheets one by one

Answer (score 0):

@Jasmine - I wasn't suggesting that you are making anything up, nor was I my comment intended to be facetious.  My point was that your question sounds self-contradictory to me.

When learning a new coding language, learning **which questions to ask** and **how to phrase and share your problem** is a skill in itself.

The fact that your file functions (a.k.a. *calculates*) 'properly'
until more identical formulas are added, sounds to me like it's ***no longer calculating properly***, so I was unsure what you meant.

As for the `size doesn't matter' comment, it's another valid point about how some people ask questions when mistakenly thinking that file size has any significance.  I've encountered and solved thousands of [seemingly unique] issues over the years but the last time I looked at the size of my file would have been back when it would've had to fit on a diskette.

Similarly, I often see questions here where the "asker" includes irrelevant statistics like the number of records in their database, as if you need to code differently for 10 records versus 10,000,000 (which isn't generally true, btw).  I can't help but chuckle at some questions where the O.P. spends more time describing the formatting of a cell than the formula it contains (that's causing the issue).  But from their point of view, it's significant.

Think of the people reading your question as sitting in your office *blindfolded* while you explain your problem.  If you're asking for (free) help from others who cannot see what you can, with zero previous knowledge, does it not make sense to make a question absolutely as clear as possible -- even if that involves Googling a word to update your terminology that *you know* is incorrect? (or is the onus on the reader to figure out what *you* mean?

**Did you click the [links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) *for you* (above) to learn how to better communicate your [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47905091/edit) to add more [specific examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and more information *as requested* and described in those links? (or was that a  *"waste of time"* as well?)  There were *specific* questions for *you* as well.

This site was frustrating for me when I first joined too but the rules and posting etiquette were not made immediately known to me by a stranger with a few seconds to spare.  I had a major learning curve and some pretty nasty comments from people since I was breaking rules I wasn't even aware of.  **I am actually breaking a major rule *right now*, can you identify it** perhaps by familiarizing yourself with the site in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)?

**Hint**: I'm probably going to get "scolded" for the method I am using to give you this advice as opposed to the short comments and links I would normally post on a question that needs more information so I or others can give an informed answer.  Some people don't like posting a question and not getting a custom written set of code promptly written ***just for them***.   Some people are grateful for every bit of advice they can get from a stranger, others never come back and find a site more suited to their needs.

Remember, **there is a ton of *existing* information on this site** and others because it's ***very* unlikely that *whatever* problem you're having has been experienced - *and solved* - by many, many people before you**. By researching as much as possible, you learn *both* about your problem *and* about which questions get "better" answers than others.

Anyhow I hope you read fast, this answer might not be here long (I wanted to be clear but without a whole whack of comments back and forth...)

Jasmine, if you're still angry with me, you can "get me back" **if** you can find the *correct* Flag button.  The answer to my question for you in is there too...  (It's not option #2, as lest not intentionally!)

**Good luck & *happy holidays to all!***

Comment: Hi, I am annoyed with your slightly patronising response which would not invoke a positive response from anyone (in my opinion if you want me to be specific!). you're right, I haven't read all the pages (I have said in the question for people not to answer until I am ready). I will have a read when I have time (i am busy at work but that's no excuse if I am posting on this site for free help as you rightly point out).

Comment: I have done much research on this. This is a problem I have been trying to solve for about a month. I found it difficult to explain this file because 1. it is fairly complicated (and I was finding it doesn't have the issue with no formulas) and 2. it has confidential information (but I should spend the time to explain it without giving anything away).